# Format parse exception “EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy”

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

My date string is: "Wed Oct 19 14:34:26 BRST 2016" and I'm trying to parse it to "dd/MM/yyyy", but I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Oct 19 14:34:26 BRST 2016" (at offset 20)
```

**the method**

```
public String dataText(int lastintervalo) {

        Date mDate = new Date();
        String dt = mDate.toString();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sdf.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        c.add(Calendar.DATE, lastintervalo);
        return sdf.format(c.getTime());

    }
```

I already searched on google and stackoverflow questions, but nothing seems to work

Comment: I tried this code, it works, I didn't get any exception and my Locale `en_IN`

Comment: what is you `Locale` ?

Comment: Since your input string is using an English weekday name, you must use an English `Locale`. If your default locale is Brazil (`pt-BR`), then the weekday would have to be `Qua` to be parsable. Since it's not, specify an English locale, so change `Locale.getDefault()` to `Locale.US`.

Comment: @Andreas I already tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: why do you parse a date that you just converted to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error message is complaining about offset 20, which is the `BRST` value, it seems that it cannot resolve the time zone.

Please try this code, that should ensure that the Brazilian time zone is recognized:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(sdf.parse("Wed Oct 19 14:34:26 BRST 2016"));
```

Since I'm in Eastern US, that prints this for me:

```
Wed Oct 19 12:34:26 EDT 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse ( 
    "Wed Oct 19 14:34:26 BRST 2016" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )
)
.toLocalDate()
.format( 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT)
                     .withLocale( Locale.UK ) 
)
```

> 19/10/16

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Use real time zone

Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `BRST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. For example, [`America/Sao_Paulo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Sao_Paulo).

So while the code below works in this particular case, I do *not* recommend exchanging data such as your input. If you have influence over the data source, change to using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for data exchange of date-time values.

> 2016-10-19T14:34:26-02:00

Even better, exchange strings as created by `ZonedDateTime` that extend ISO 8601 format by appending the time zone name in square brackets.

> 2016-10-19T14:34:26-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

Best of all, usually, is to convert such values to UTC before exchanging data. In java.time, call `toInstant().toString()` to do this. Generally best to work in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), applying a time zone only where required such as presentation to the user.

> 2016-10-19T16:34:26Z

## Example code

```
String input = "Wed Oct 19 14:34:26 BRST 2016";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2016-10-19T14:34:26-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

To see the same moment in UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

> instant.toString(): 2016-10-19T16:34:26Z

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

> ld.toString(): 2016-10-19

To generate strings in other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` class. Generally best to let java.time localize automatically.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US or Locale.ITALY etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale( l );
String output = ld.format( f );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..It may work

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                    Locale.ENGLISH);
```